# Screen sharing over QuickBlox Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, quickblox, screensharing

I would like to use screen sharing with the JavaScript SDK of QuickBlox. The Android and the iOS QB-SDKs support already this feature, but I can’t find any hints for JavaScript support in the current version (2.5.0).

Are there some plans for screen sharing with JavaScript in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with QuickBlox JS SDK, but it needs some additional logic.
WebRTC API does not provide a way to natively share your screen, so Chrome/Firefox browsers plugins are needed here.

For example, I tried some time ago this logic
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/#7396622660871782

so you just pass another object to QuickBlox 'session.getUserMedia':

```
session.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: {mozMediaSource: 'screen'}).
then(successCallback).
catch(errorCallback);
```

https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-web#Access_local_media_stream

and that's all

BUT

it needs to install Chrome/Firefox screen sharing plugin.

The normal way here is that each developer has its own plugin, with own App/Company name. So you can use the source code of that plugin for Chrome/Firefox from link above and build your own.